# How many data packets does it take to log in to facebook?

Tags: linux-networking, packet-capture, packet

I want to find out how many packets are sent when visiting a site on the web. What's a good program that would help me get this kind of data?

Comment: Just run a capture with `wireshark` and see for yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could obtain the number by using [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) on your machine. This is a very common packet analyzer.

Here is some [good documentation](http://www.howtogeek.com/104278/how-to-use-wireshark-to-capture-filter-and-inspect-packets/) on how to use it. There's a plethora of resources on it though.